# Alignment and spacing of an unordered list

Tags: html, css

Is there any cross browser css only solution to format the list below with the following qualities?

```
<p>a demo</p>
<ol>
    <li>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>the quick brown fox jumps over <br/>the lazy dog</li>
</ol>
```

1. List items bulletted with letters a. b. c. etc.
2. Bullet letters left aligned with each other and the paragraph above.
3. A couple of characters worth of space between the bullet letters and the item text.
4. Lines of text within the same list item are left aligned.

Edit:
Before the trigger happy who assume this is easy close it down, this is the closest I've got:

```
ol { list-style: lower-alpha; padding-left: 0; }
li { margin-left: 1em; padding-left: 1em; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/htopjbu3/

Which satisfies 1 3 and 4 in Firefox but not Chrome. As for 2 I can't find any way of getting the bullet letters to left align with each other, rather than right align at the dots apart from using `list-style-position: inside`, which breaks 3 and 4.

Comment: Yes, there is. How about showing the specific problem you're having?

Comment: Better create a wireframe first... and then try to achieve the tasks step by step. You've to come up with your code man..

Comment: Yeah.... I thought it was going to be easy too, thanks @Shomz.

Answer (score 0):

For point 1:

```
<p>a demo</p>
<ol type="a">
    <li>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>the quick brown fox jumps over <br/>the lazy dog</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It's working but : "The "start" and "type" attributes were deprecated in HTML 4.01, but IS supported in HTML5." Source : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp

Comment: Thanks, but requirement 1 is just a scene setter for the other three really which are proving difficult to achieve in combination. Also the requirement is for a css only solution, so I'm using list-style: lower-alpha for 1 anyway.

Comment: @Promo Don't use W3Schools. It's been known over the years to be riddled with inaccuracies. I suggest https://developer.mozilla.org or better yet, the spec itself: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element Also, any reason why HTML 4.01 is being used?

Comment: Hi @matthewpavkov. If you're referring to the self closing br, it's just to keep jsfiddle happy.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `<span>` tag

```css
   ol {list-style-type: lower-alpha;}
span {margin-left:10px;}
```

```html
    <ol>
      <li><span>Coffee</span></li>
      <li><span>Tea</span></li>
      <li><span>Coca Cola</span></li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a css only solution ideally.

Answer (score 0):

`1.2em` works just fine for me in Chrome and Firefox (and you can always specify it in pixels), all 4 rules are correct: https://jsfiddle.net/htopjbu3/1/

```css
ol { list-style: lower-alpha; padding-left: 0; }
li { margin-left: 1.2em; padding-left: 1em; }
```

```html
<p>a demo</p>
<ol>
    <li>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>the quick brown fox jumps over <br/>the lazy dog</li>
</ol>
```

However, if by #2 you want the letters and the dots to be aligned vertically, I'm afraid you'd have to use a monospace font because there's no other way to align, say, `m.` and `i.`

Remember, the more CSS rules you define, the less browser-default rules will be applied and that helps a lot with the cross-browser issues (and that's what those reset CSS files are doing, for the good and for the bad of it).

Comment: Thanks, but the bullet "a" is way to the right of the paragraph "a" above in Firefox for me. And on #2 I don't want both dots and the letters aligned, just the left edge of the letters. In your demo it's just the dots.

Comment: You're welcome. Really? The `a`s look pixel perfect in my browser. Yes, for #2 I can only suggest monospace fonts... how does this look in your browser: https://jsfiddle.net/htopjbu3/2/ Not sure if there's a way to use monospace just on the labels without modifying the markup...

Comment: Your first example looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/exzvfjyw/ to me in Firefox 36 on Windows. And changing the font is not an option I'm afraid. Mono spacing shouldn't really come into it given that it's just a matter of left rather than right alignment.

Comment: Oh, I see... Hm, I'm not sure you'll be able to do it - list elements have always lacked the ability to be specifically designed, probably because the more powerful did HTML get, the less useful the ordered list elements have become because they're easy to recreate using `p`/`span` elements. Let's hope someone comes up with a pure CSS solution.